# Groovy each() method does not iterate properly

Tags: groovy, each

I came across a strange behavior of the each() method when trying this code:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''
<list>
    <item a="1">a</item>
    <item a="2">b</item>
    <item a="1">c</item>
</list>
''')

def i = 0
xml.'**'.findAll { it.@a=='1' }.each {
    println "hi" + i
}
```

The result is only `hi0`, however I would expect `hi0hi1`. Is this behavior a bug or per language design? The second result is only provided if I write `println "hi" + i++` instead of the current closure body, so when the content is different for each item...

Answer (score 5):

Your `i` variable is not being incremented because there's nothing that tells it to increment. The way your code is currently written, I would expect the output to be:

```
hi0
hi0
```

I think what you are looking for is `eachWithIndex`, which provides the closure with two arguments - the current item and the index of the item. Your code would then look like this:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''
<list>
    <item a="1">a</item>
    <item a="2">b</item>
    <item a="1">c</item>
</list>
''')

xml.'**'.findAll { it.@a=='1' }.eachWithIndex { item, i ->
    println "hi" + i
}
```

This results in an output of:

```
hi0
hi1
```

Comment: many thanks for the feedback. And sorry, my mistake, the question was not exact (tried to debug the issue for many hours before, so was a bit tired :). I would also expect the outcome to be exactly what you wrote, `hi0\nhi0`, however I got it only once, so `hi0`. It seems to be executed twice only if I add something that changes over the iterations. A counter, timestamp, etc. (but timestamp only if it changes, so if it is only the day eg, then it prints it still once). very strange behavour. I am using grails 2.4.4...

Comment: Running the code you provided results in two lines of "hi0." You can see this by running your code in your local Groovy console or via the Groovy web console at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/. I would guess that your example code isn't an accurate representation of what's happening in your actual code. Perhaps your `findAll` closure is not filtering the way you would expect it to?

Comment: yes, it should result two, now I checked again and still it produces one. Now just copying and pasting the code directly (the def i=0 was missed before): `def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''
<list>
    <item a="1">a</item>
    <item a="2">b</item>
    <item a="1">c</item>
</list>
''')

def i = 0
xml.'**'.findAll { it.@a=='1' }.each {
 println "hi" + i
}` and the result is: `|Running script scripts/test.groovy ...
hi0
|Script scripts/test.groovy complete!

`. Tomorrow I will check it out at the workplace and compare the bytecode that is generated as this is annoying... :)